# Kafka test containers and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, testcontainers

So i have set up an integration test for my spring boot application, with kafka test container using

```
    KAFKA_CONTAINER = (KafkaContainer)(new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka").withTag("5.4.3"))).withReuse(true);
```

The test works fine when producing messages, however a consumer doesnt seem to consume at all. I think its down to schema registry being a mock

```
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=mock://localhost
```

So i decied to use the following to consume messages, with a mock registry. Using KafkaUtils. however it doesnt seem to work

```
  public static KafkaConsumer<String, CarDTO> createEventConsumer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
    props.put(
        ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "mock://testUrl");
    props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, "true");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "kafkatest");
    return new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
  }
```

and polling code is as follows:

the cosumer has been subscribed to correct topic, as if i change the avro to

```
while (i>0) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, CarDTO> records = storeReplenOrderDTOKafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (ConsumerRecord<String, StoreReplenOrderDTO> record : records) {
                System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
                i = 0;

            }
```

The error i get is as follows:

```
Error deserializing key/value for partition test-topic-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
...
...
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject Not Found; error code: 40401
    at app//io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.MockSchemaRegistryClient.getSchemaBySubjectAndIdFromRegistry(MockSchemaRegistryClient.java:202)
```

interestingly i change the following to, then i am able to get the key but not the object

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
```

im not sure what i need to set to get this working with mock registry.

Comment: Tangetial comment: If you are using kafka and you want your tests to be fast, write them in such a way that they expect kafka to be running continously (so don't start or clean up anything in your tests!). Start kafka, schema registry, your DB, etc from your build tool (maven, gradle, etc) **once** and then use that instance for everything you do. For example, with gradle, you could start up a docker compose with all of your dependencies and have them continuously running.

Comment: Here is a solution with schema registry as a separate container https://stackoverflow.com/a/75389041/9068895

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to get this working, instead of using mock:// for kafka registry, i instead used wiremock to stub the response. |For the avro, once i did this my consumer was able to consume/