# DNS failure Integration testing a Kafka Streams app with TestContainers and a network alias

Tags: docker, integration-testing, apache-kafka-streams, testcontainers

I'm having an unexpected issue trying to link my app under test running in Docker to a Kafka image also running in another Docker container.

I am trying to run by adapting the solution from Alex here: [Testcontainers SchemaRegistry can't connect to Kafka container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388650/testcontainers-schemaregistry-cant-connect-to-kafka-container) and have the SchemaRegistryContainer as given in that answer. I am then supplementing that with a Docker image of my test app using the same Docker network.

Based on the documentation on Multi-container usage here https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/

> If your test needs to run some other Docker container which needs
> access to Kafka, do the following: 
> ... info on running on same Docker network ...
>
>  Use `kafka.getNetworkAliases().get(0)+":9092"` as bootstrap server location. 
>  Or just give your Kafka container a network alias of your liking.

I tried using the first option, but it complained of not being able to resolve the address by DNS, so I tried setting an alias 'kafka' and connecting via `PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`. This also led to the error `WARN - Couldn't resolve server PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka`

If I shell into my running container, however, I am able to `wget kafka` and it resolves to an IP (192.168.128.2 in this case).

I am half anticipating to run into issues with `ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`, but this seems to be that the Streams app (or at least the Admin client in the streams app) is not able to use the Docker DNS service correctly and isn't even getting to the stage where it can't find the URL returned by Kafka.

Comment: A bit of investigation and I suspect that the IDE/JRE makes the app under test look as though it's running from the host machine instead of the docker container. It's accepting breakpoints in the code under test (even though it's running under Docker) and trying to get the IP address of the container via DNS in the test scripts fails in a similar way