# Containers SchemaRegistry can't connect to Kafka container

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, testcontainers

I tried to use this approach to [Testcontainers SchemaRegistry can't connect to Kafka container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388650/testcontainers-schemaregistry-cant-connect-to-kafka-container) to start a schema registry test container, but it don't work

First try was:

```
   public SchemaRegistryContainer withKafka( final KafkaContainer kafkaContainer ) {
      withNetwork( kafkaContainer.getNetwork() );
      withEnv( "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "kafka-confluent-cp-schema-registry" );
      withEnv( "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:" + SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT );
      withEnv( "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers() );
      return self();
   }
```

Error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:165)
        at io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus.isKafkaReady(ClusterStatus.java:147)
        at io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand.main(KafkaReadyCommand.java:149)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listNodes
```

Then i tried this:

```
   public SchemaRegistryContainer withKafka( final KafkaContainer kafkaContainer ) {
      withNetwork( kafkaContainer.getNetwork() );
      withEnv( "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "schema-registry" );
      withEnv( "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:" + SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT );
      withEnv( "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "PLAINTEXT://" + kafkaContainer.getNetworkAliases().get( 0 ) + ":9092" );
      return self();
   }
```

Error

```
2023-04-27 07:46:35,687] WARN Couldn't resolve server PLAINTEXT://tc-HJrDbND5:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for tc-HJrDbND5 (org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils)
[2023-04-27 07:46:35,687] ERROR Error while running kafka-ready. (io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:553)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.Admin.create(Admin.java:144)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:49)
        at io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus.isKafkaReady(ClusterStatus.java:136)
        at io.confluent.admin.utils.cli.KafkaReadyCommand.main(KafkaReadyCommand.java:149)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:505)
        ... 4 more
```

Anyone have any ideas what else I can test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Couldn't resolve server PLAINTEXT://tc-HJrDbND5:9092`

You should remove `PLAINTEXT` prefix.

Make sure the containers are on the same network bridge, which I've see you've tried by `withNetwork()`.

Otherwise, modify the listeners of the Kafka container though its own environment variables, otherwise you'll get Kafka client errors even without Schema Registry (I assume you've already tested that?)

Comment: Thanks this was the issue changed it to:
"withEnv( "SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", kafkaContainer.getNetworkAliases().get( 0 ) + ":9092" );"