# Testcontainers-java times out waiting for container when run in TeamCity/docker, but fine in MacOS / MacOS+docker

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka, teamcity, testcontainers

I am trying to run an integration test for Kafka Streams using TestContainers with Schema Registry

I am able to get it running locally (MacOS), and locally within Docker (needs `TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE='host.docker.internal'` setting), but when I try to run it from a Linux agent in TeamCity it appears not to be able to check whether the schema registry container is running.

I am basically using the setup from this SO answer for my Kafka/SR containers: [Testcontainers SchemaRegistry can't connect to Kafka container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75388650/testcontainers-schemaregistry-cant-connect-to-kafka-container)

The crash seems to occur at the `SCHEMA_REGISTRY.withKafka(KAFKA).start();` stage with the following appearing in the log: `"Timed out waiting for URL to be accessible (http://172.17.0.1:32833/subjects should return HTTP [200])"`

The log output from the failed container which follows is unfortunately truncated, but appears to show the SR container running as expected, so I think it's just that how it's trying to connect to the container is incorrect.

I've tried increasing the timeout, setting the HOST_OVERRIDE to `host.docker.internal` (this makes it worse - it can't find ryuk) and setting the network to `host`. The command to run the container in the script is
`docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --network host <container name>`, which works on MacOS, but not TC/Linux.

The SchemaRegistry container config from that earlier answer is:

```
public class SchemaRegistryContainer extends GenericContainer<SchemaRegistryContainer> {
    public static final String SCHEMA_REGISTRY_IMAGE =
            "confluentinc/cp-schema-registry";
    public static final int SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT = 8081;

    public SchemaRegistryContainer() {
        this(CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_VERSION);
    }

    public SchemaRegistryContainer(String version) {
        super(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_IMAGE + ":" + version);

        waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/subjects").forStatusCode(200));
        withExposedPorts(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT);
    }

    public SchemaRegistryContainer withKafka(KafkaContainer kafka) {
        return withKafka(kafka.getNetwork(), kafka.getNetworkAliases().get(0) + ":9092");
    }

    public SchemaRegistryContainer withKafka(Network network, String bootstrapServers) {
        withNetwork(network);
        withEnv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME", "schema-registry");
        withEnv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:8081");
        withEnv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS", "PLAINTEXT://" + bootstrapServers);
        return self();
    }
}
```

The code to start my containers is:

```
            KafkaContainer.KAFKA.withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3)).start();
            KafkaContainer.SCHEMA_REGISTRY.withKafka(KafkaContainer.KAFKA).withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3)).start();
```

(I have tried longer timeouts)

Comment: `--network host` shouldn't work on Mac. `host.docker.internal` only works on Mac (that address is set by Docker Desktop, so not available on Linux)

Comment: Also, you've set `withEnv("SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS", "http://0.0.0.0:8081");`... So why is your error not using port 8081?

Comment: I suspect the 8081 issue will be the withExposedPorts - TestContainers randomises exposed ports to avoid clashes

I have it working on Mac fine - both bare and in Docker. My issue is getting it working in a Linux environment hence throwing things at it (network and host.docker.internal) and seeing if anything stuck - they didn't work in Linux hence coming here

Comment: Yeah, not sure. I have not used Schema Registry in a TestContainer. [Mocks have always worked fine for me with unit tests](https://github.com/bakdata/fluent-kafka-streams-tests/blob/master/schema-registry-mock/README.md#schema-registry-mock). Plus, they run faster than starting Docker containers. But are you sure the Kafka container itself starts? If not, the schema registry wont start. Can you access logs from either container?

Comment: well I *assume* so - the Kafka container should have a startup check (in the same way that the SR one is failing), but I've honestly not checked. I may look into the mock approach

Comment: OK - so I've managed to get it working with the mock SR (after some initial problems with Maven/Jackson), so thanks for that. I think the original problem still stands though - I suspect it's an insufficient setup of the networking